# php split Array via [name] into groups to save in MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, split

**output via print_r in php from jquery.serilizeArray()**

```
Array ( 
     [pnr_item_2] => 2 
     [pkt_item_2] => Hosting L 
     [desc_item_2] => Domain + Hosting 
     [qty_item_2] => 9 
     [price_item_2] => 12.4 
     [pnr_item_1] => 1 
     [pkt_item_1] => HostingXXL 
     [desc_item_1] => 20GB, 1x.de 
     [qty_item_1] => 2 
     [price_item_1] => 15.5 
     [pnr_item_3] => 3 
     [pkt_item_3] => Domain 
     [desc_item_3] => Standarddomain 
     [qty_item_3] => 6 
     [price_item_3] => 5 
     [pnr_item_4] => 3 
     [pkt_item_4] => Domain 
     [desc_item_4] => Standarddomain 
     [qty_item_4] => 7 
     [price_item_4] => 5 
     [action] => save 
     [mysql] => update 
     [total] => 351.1 
)
```

Does exist a possibility to split an Array in groups by using the `_item_##`-number? 
I want to save items to my first MySQL table, action is the executet function, which I get via `$_POST[action]` and `[total]` have to be saved in a extra (2nd) MySQL-table.

Comment: huh? please revise question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my guess at the question's meaning ;)

```
//$yourArr = array(all,your,input);

$action = $yourArr['action'];
$mysql = $yourArr['mysql'];
$total = $yourArr['total'];
unset( $yourArr['action'] , $yourArr['mysql'] , $yourArr['total'] );

foreach ($yourArr as $k => $v) {
  list($type,$num) = explode('_item_',$k);
  $items[$num][$type] = $v;
}
```

Than you have, for example:

```
$items = array(
  [2]['pnr'] => 2, 
  [2]['pkt'] => 'Hosting L',
  [2][['desc_item'] => 'Domain + Hosting'
  ...
  );
```

*disclaimer: I didn't actually test this*

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array:

```
$items = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    if(stripos($key, '_item_' !== false)) {
        $items[$key] = $value;
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Then `$items` contain all elements that have `_item_` in the key and `$array` the rest.

But easier would be to save `total` first and remove `action`, `mysql` and `total` from the array. So just reversing both operations.